# How to interact (read/write/delete) files in S3 bucket directly through streamlit webapp?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, streamlit

I am trying to load a file to s3 bucket through streamlit web UI. Also next step is to read or delete files present in s3 bucket through streamlit app in an interactive way .. I have written a code to upload file on streamlit app but failing in loading it to s3 bucket.

Comment: Have tried using the boto3 library?  It has various API calls that will allow you to do this.

Answer (score 2):

We have a pretty detailed [doc](https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/tutorials/databases/aws-s3) on this. You can use s3fs to make the connection, e.g.:

```
# streamlit_app.py

import streamlit as st
import s3fs
import os

# Create connection object.
# `anon=False` means not anonymous, i.e. it uses access keys to pull data.
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)

# Retrieve file contents.
# Uses st.experimental_memo to only rerun when the query changes or after 10 min.
@st.experimental_memo(ttl=600)
def read_file(filename):
    with fs.open(filename) as f:
        return f.read().decode("utf-8")

content = read_file("testbucket-jrieke/myfile.csv")

# Print results.
for line in content.strip().split("\n"):
    name, pet = line.split(",")
    st.write(f"{name} has a :{pet}:")
```